# Changing URL in VisualSVN

Tags: apache, svn, url, visualsvn-server, mod-dav-svn

Have 5 year old server ready to decommission and have new server with VisualSVN just installed.  Our old server had a very memorable URL such as svn://company.com.  Now the path on the new server is terrible - https://server.company.com:8443/svn/MyRepo.  I'd much prefer to have something much shorter with a dozen engineers needing to use it.

I've read other posts saying we should visit httpd.conf but I can't even find that file in the conf folder.

I've also read that VisualSVN support states they cannot support this as of mid-2009.  They also suggest not changing the httpd.conf file.

Anyone have answers on the topic?

Answer (score 1):

OK, lets split problem on separate small tasks

- Convert server.company.com into company.com

Pure DNS issue, write needed data in DNS-zone for internal domain or use local hosts-file

- Convert company.com:8443 into company.com

Start *VisualSVN Server* (plain VisualSVN is SVN-plugin for Visual Studio) on 80 port

- Convert company.com/svn/ path into company.com/

Read [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/402671/99868) in the part "How to have DAV-SVN in the site-root" ("Implementation", p.3)

- Remove repository name from URL

Default config **implies using more than one repo from one server**. If it is not your case and you have one repo, you can modify Location data and use wanted and needed SVN directive (we'll consult with [Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) for this, "Basic Apache Configuration" topic)

> You can instruct Apache to delegate the handling of all URLs... to a
>   DAV provider whose repository is located at /var/svn/repository using
>   the following httpd.conf syntax:

```
<Location ...>
  ...
  SVNPath /var/svn/repository
</Location>
```

Note - `/var/svn/repository` in example is **directory**, which **contain immediately our single repository**

Viola! Task solved?!

When VisualSVN team tell about

> not changing the httpd.conf file

they have in mind (I think) the need for the user

- have a copy of customized httpd.conf, because on every VisualSVN Server update httpd.conf will be replaced with default
- self-integrate their own changes to changed by developers configuration
- be intelligent and smart and don't complaint to VisualSVN team about troubles, caused by local changes, not by problems in vanulla product

Answer (score 1):

[Beginning with VisualSVN Server 3.5, it is possible to adjust the URL to your repositories.](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/3.5/) In other words, prior to version 3.5 the URL always looked like *https://example**/svn**/myrepo/*. It is now possible to change the "/svn" part to "/repos" or any other prefix you'd like. Moreover, you can completely remove the prefix.

Follow these steps to customize the URL prefix:

1. Start VisualSVN Server Manager.
2. Go to Action | Properties.
3. Select Network tab.
4. Select Customize under Repositories URL:

You can select "Empty URL prefix" option to remove the "/svn" prefix completely or select "Custom URL prefix" and specify the prefix you'd like to use in the URL (for example, "repos").